# Keras LSTM input dimension setting with attention class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I was trying to train a LSTM model using keras but I think I got something wrong here.

I got an error of

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The code is in the following link:

https://androidkt.com/text-classification-using-attention-mechanism-in-keras/

When I tried to apply the code using attention class, first it gives me that attention is not defined, then I used Attention " in Capital Letter for Attention", then it gave me the error.

The Attention class is as follows:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
class Attention(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Attention, self).__init__()
        self.W1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.W2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units)
        self.V = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

    def call(self, features, hidden):
        hidden_with_time_axis = tf.expand_dims(hidden, 1)
        score = tf.nn.tanh(self.W1(features) + self.W2(hidden_with_time_axis))
        attention_weights = tf.nn.softmax(self.V(score), axis=1)
        context_vector = attention_weights * features
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        return context_vector, attention_weights

The rest of the code in the link I mentioned before.


2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
import os
lstm = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM
                                     (rnn_cell_size,
                                      dropout=0.3,
                                      return_sequences=True,
                                      return_state=True,
                                      recurrent_activation='relu',
                                      recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'), name="bi_lstm_0")(embedded_sequences)

lstm, forward_h, forward_c, backward_h, backward_c = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional \
    (tf.keras.layers.LSTM
     (rnn_cell_size,
      dropout=0.2,
      return_sequences=True,
      return_state=True,
      recurrent_activation='relu',
      recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform'))(lstm)



state_h = Concatenate()([forward_h, backward_h])
state_c = Concatenate()([forward_c, backward_c])

**context_vector, attention_weights = Attention(lstm, state_h)**

output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(context_vector)

model = keras.Model(inputs=sequence_input, outputs=output)

# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all guys, I found the answer:

context_vector, attention_weights = Attention(32)(lstm, state_h)